# Regex for match sequence digits in Amazon Redshift

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

I am write a regex that matches sequence increasing numbers in string. It works fine in test, but does not works in Amazon Redshift.
Can anyone help me out here

Regex:

```
^(?:[^1]*)1(?:[^2]*)2(?:[^3]*)3(?:.*)$
```

For example it match strings (correct):

```
123
1331213
12222211323
17397462453
1abcd2abcd3abcd
```

https://regex101.com/r/zkUMxG/1/

When I use it in Amazon, get error:

```
Error running query: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator. The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: '(?>>>HERE>>>:[^1]*)1(?'. DETAIL: ----------------------------------------------- error: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator. The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: '(?>>>HERE>>>:[^1]*)1(?'. code: 8002 context: T_regexp_init query: 19124520 location: funcs_expr.cpp:185 process: query1_107_19124520 [pid=15061] -----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Redshift regex is POSIX-based ([proof](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html)). [POSIX Basic Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) don't support non-capturing groups that your `^(?:[^1]*)1(?:[^2]*)2(?:[^3]*)3(?:.*)$` expression contains: there are four `(?:...)` patterns.

Remove the groups altogher as you do not plan on using them:

```
^[^1]*1[^2]*2[^3]*3.*$
```